# Converting a table with a key and comment field into a key and row for every word in the column field

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with unstructured data I am trying to analyze to try to build a relational lookup.  I do not have use of word cloud software.

I really have no idea how to solve this problem.  Searching for solutions has lead me to tools that might do this for me that cost money, not coded solutions.

Basically my data looks like this:

```
CK1          CK2          Comment
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1            A           This is a comment.
 2            A           Another comment here.
```

And this is what I need to create:

```
CK1          CK2          Words
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1            A           This
 1            A           is
 1            A           a
 1            A           comment.
 2            A           Another
 2            A           comment
 2            A           here.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is tokenize a string using a space as a Delimiter. In the SQL world people often refer to functions that do this as a "Splitter". The potential pitfall of using a splitter for this type of thing is how words can be separated by multiple spaces, tabs, CHAR(10)'s, CHAR(13)'s, CHAR()'s, etc. Poor grammar, such as not adding a space after a period results in this:

```
" End of sentence.Next sentence"
```

**sentence.Next** is returned as a word.

The way I like to tokenize human text is to:

1. Replace any text that isn't a character with a space
2. Replace duplicate spaces
3. Trim the string
4. Split the newly transformed string using a space as the delimiter.

Below is my solution followed by the DDL to create the functions used.

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE (CK1 INT, CK2 CHAR(1), Comment VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT @yourtable (CK1, CK2, Comment)
VALUES
(1,'A','This is a typical comment...Follewed by another...'),
(2,'A','This comment has  double  spaces  and       tabs and even carriage
returns!');

-- Solution
SELECT      t.CK1, t.CK2, split.itemNumber, split.itemIndex, split.itemLength, split.item
FROM        @yourtable                                              AS t
CROSS APPLY samd.patReplace(t.Comment,'[^a-zA-Z ]',' ')             AS c1
CROSS APPLY samd.removeDupChar8K(c1.newString,' ')                  AS c2 
CROSS APPLY samd.delimitedSplitAB8K(LTRIM(RTRIM(c2.NewString)),' ') AS split;
```

**Results (truncated for brevity):**

```
CK1         CK2  itemNumber           itemIndex   itemLength  item
----------- ---- -------------------- ----------- ----------- --------------
1           A    1                    1           4           This
1           A    2                    6           2           is
1           A    3                    9           1           a
1           A    4                    11          7           typical
1           A    5                    19          7           comment
...
2           A    1                    1           4           This
2           A    2                    6           7           comment
2           A    3                    14          3           has
2           A    4                    18          6           double
...
```

Note that the splitter I'm using is based of Jeff Moden's Delimited Split8K with a couple tweeks.

Functions used:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.rangeAB
(
  @low  bigint, 
  @high bigint, 
  @gap  bigint,
  @row1 bit
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
WITH L1(N) AS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM (VALUES
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0)) T(N) -- 90 values 
),
L2(N)  AS (SELECT 1 FROM L1 a CROSS JOIN L1 b CROSS JOIN L1 c),
iTally AS (SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM L2 a CROSS JOIN L2 b)
SELECT r.RN, r.OP, r.N1, r.N2
FROM
(
  SELECT
    RN = 0,
    OP = (@high-@low)/@gap,
    N1 = @low,
    N2 = @gap+@low
  WHERE @row1 = 0
  UNION ALL -- COALESCE required in the TOP statement below for error handling purposes
  SELECT TOP (ABS((COALESCE(@high,0)-COALESCE(@low,0))/COALESCE(@gap,0)+COALESCE(@row1,1)))
    RN = i.rn,
    OP = (@high-@low)/@gap+(2*@row1)-i.rn,
    N1 = (i.rn-@row1)*@gap+@low,
    N2 = (i.rn-(@row1-1))*@gap+@low
  FROM iTally AS i
  ORDER BY i.rn
) AS r
WHERE @high&@low&@gap&@row1 IS NOT NULL AND @high >= @low AND @gap > 0;
    GO

CREATE FUNCTION samd.NGrams8k
(
  @string VARCHAR(8000), -- Input string
  @N      INT            -- requested token size
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
SELECT
  position   = r.RN,
  token      = SUBSTRING(@string, CHECKSUM(r.RN), @N)
FROM  dbo.rangeAB(1, LEN(@string)+1-@N,1,1) AS r
WHERE @N > 0 AND @N <= LEN(@string);
GO

    CREATE FUNCTION samd.patReplace8K
(
  @string  VARCHAR(8000),
  @pattern VARCHAR(50),
  @replace VARCHAR(20)
) 
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
SELECT newString = 
  (
    SELECT   CASE WHEN @string = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(8000)) THEN CAST('' AS VARCHAR(8000))
                  WHEN @pattern+@replace+@string IS NOT NULL THEN 
                    CASE WHEN PATINDEX(@pattern,token COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)=0
                         THEN ng.token ELSE @replace END END
    FROM     samd.NGrams8K(@string, 1) AS ng
    ORDER BY ng.position
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(8000)');
GO

    CREATE FUNCTION samd.delimitedSplitAB8K
(
  @string    VARCHAR(8000), -- input string
  @delimiter CHAR(1)        -- delimiter
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
SELECT
  itemNumber   = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.p),
  itemIndex    = CHECKSUM(ISNULL(NULLIF(d.p+1, 0),1)),
  itemLength   = CHECKSUM(item.ln),
  item         = SUBSTRING(@string, d.p+1, item.ln)
FROM (VALUES (DATALENGTH(@string))) AS l(s) -- length of the string
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL -- for handling leading delimiters
  SELECT ng.position
  FROM   samd.NGrams8K(@string, 1) AS ng
  WHERE  token = @delimiter
) AS d(p) -- delimiter.position
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(  --LEAD(d.p, 1, l.s+l.d) OVER (ORDER BY d.p) - (d.p+l.d)
  ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@string,d.p+1),0)-(d.p+1), l.s-d.p))) AS item(ln);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveDupChar8K(@string varchar(8000), @char char(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN

SELECT NewString = 
 replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
 @string COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN,
 replicate(@char,33), @char), --33
 replicate(@char,17), @char), --17
 replicate(@char,9 ), @char), -- 9
 replicate(@char,5 ), @char), -- 5
 replicate(@char,3 ), @char), -- 3 
 replicate(@char,2 ), @char), -- 2
 replicate(@char,2 ), @char); -- 2
GO
```

Comment: Wow.  This broke down into a much more complex problem I imagined it would be.  Let me play with this a little bit, it looks like could do what I'm looking for.  If it is I'll come back and mark this as the answer.

Comment: Ok, so I've managed to use what you've provided to solve the problem, that's great.  I appreciate your help here.  However, before I can mark your answer as correct, I need you to add the 'RemoveDupChar8K' function to your functions used list.  It is missing from the example, which prevents this answer from being correct as-is.  I pulled it from your Github repo.  If you can add that function to your function reference, we're good to go.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Alan.  I've parsed documents into a table in the past but that was program into DB; I had not yet tried to do it the other way so I was thinking up excessively complex solutions that involved ETL with applications.  I'm going to follow up on this and check out Jeff Moden's writings on his splitter module, I think we could probably use some of his work to help us with other problems in the past that we've attacked using sloppier methods.

Answer (score 0):

1) If we are using SQL Server 2016 and above then we should probably
    use the built-in function STRING_SPLIT

```
-- SQL 2016and above
DECLARE @txt NVARCHAR(100) = N'This is a comment.'
select [value] from STRING_SPLIT(@txt, ' ')
```

2) Only if 1 does not fit, then if the number of separation (the space in our case) is less then 3 which fit your sample data, then we should probably use PARSENAME

```
-- BEFORE SQL 2016 if we have less than 4 parts
DECLARE @txt NVARCHAR(100) = N'This is a comment.'
DECLARE @Temp NVARCHAR(200) = REPLACE (@txt,'.','@')
SELECT t FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4))T1(n)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Temp,' ','.'),T1.n), '@','.'))T2(t)
```

3) Only if the 1 and 2 does not fit, then we should use SQLCLR function

http://dataeducation.com/sqlclr-string-splitting-part-2-even-faster-even-more-scalable/

4) Only if we cannot use 1,2 and we cannot use SQLCLR (which implies a real problematic administration and has nothing with security since you can have all the SQLCLR function in a read-only database for the use of all users, as I explain in my lectures), then you can use T-SQL and create UDF.

https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: STRING_SPLIT does not guarantee order, the OP did not specify if that order matters or if they have 2016. The PARSE_NAME solution is not realistic (I'm sure the "comment" field  will have more than four words). As a Huuuuge advocate of SQLCLR I don't think I'd enable CLR for on a system just for this kind of thing. The decision to enable CLR is not trivial.

Comment: (1) The word "order" was not mentioned!!!! (2) If you have any understanding on SQL Server then you should know that the order of the result SET IN NOT guarantee unless you have ORDER BY!!! this means that there is no order to the result SET in the image! (3) Uninviting for legit response is rude! If someone does not want to say thanks for the attempt to help then he should at least NOT harm the person who tried to help! ** `and this feature is one of the reasons I HATE stackoverflow system and prefer to help people on MSDN forums`** .It totally reduce my motivation to help people

Comment: There is no column(s) in the result SET in the image which fit to sort the result and get the order of the original sentence! `The person who unvoted my answer has not understanding of SQL Server!` and should read this document [The order in which rows are returned in a result set are not guaranteed unless an ORDER BY clause is specified.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Oh... I really hate this interface where any child without any understanding can UN-Vote legit messages, reduce points, confuse the OP with misleading information, and more.... really bad feature... It is a good time for me to drop from this thread and probably and move to help people in other places. REALLY ANNOYING FEATURE `:-(`

Comment: typo: "`(3) Uninviting for legit response is rude!`" > I meant "`(3) Un-voting for legit response is rude!`"

Comment: @AlanBurstein (1) "the OP did not specify if that order matters or if they have 2016" which mean we should give him the solution for latest version and not guess and give bad solution! (2) "PARSE_NAME solution is not realistic" only if you know the OP system and you know it (which I do not and the sample data does not show it) and if not then you should give him the better solution and not mislead him! (3) "decision to enable CLR is not trivial"  - TRUE! but this mean that it might fit him, and you must mention the better solution and not mislead him (4) Regarding the "order" I wrote above.

Comment: All I was saying is, for something this simple, you did not post a working solution unless the OP has SQL Server 2016 or a "comment" field with a maximum of three words. There's nothing wrong with CLR but, again, for something as simple as this - enabling CLR integration and pulling in a CLR splitter is like pole-vaulting over an Ant hill IMHO. 

Create some sample data, update your answer to include DDL to show how you would use STRING_SPLIT and I'll happily Upvote your answer.

Comment: @AlanBurstein is not my place to teach you if you do not want to learn. Moreover, it is not my place to educate you regarding rude behavior. I will say in public only that unless someone can read minds or have more information which was not provided in the question, then UN-VOTE my answer shows poor understanding about SQL Sever and how it works or simply making multiple assumptions with no base (I have no idea if these are correct or not, but they have no base = pure guessing). I do not know who did it and what was his goal and I will open an investigation, but I can say that it was rude.

Comment: In theory even if an answer does not fit (`which is not the case!`) then Un-Vote legit answer is rude. You do not have to Vote-up if you don't have the understanding of the topic, but reducing from someone who try to help and wrote legit answer (again even if the answer does not fit) is RUDE AND POOR BEHAVIOR! Anyway, this is not the case here and the answer I wrote gives multiple options for different cases which fit **the information we got in the question** (without assumptions like what version, what limitation)! By the way, assumptions might be good, if they explicitly presented as such

Comment: Ops...funny typo!!! "`I will open an investigation`" should be "I will **NOT** open an investigation" :-)

Comment: This pissing contest you guys have gotten into down here is one of the reasons why I don't bother trying to recover my original SO account.

Ronen, your answer includes ideas that I could have used to help fix my problem, I am using SQL 2016 and this does cut up my comment field like I had requested in the question.  I chose Andrew's answer because it was comprehensive, with built-in solutions to issues I did not anticipate in the work I was doing.  STRING_SPLIT lead me to discover I needed to account for multiple delimiters and the order of the words in this text field.

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine and much easier and faster if the data you're trying to tokenize is clean.  Unfortunately my data is not clean and many of the things Andrew notes about typographical errors and the difference in spaces are things I know exist in my data and have to be accounted for.

Comment: @user11047859 this is basically exactly what I tried to explain. I gave a perfect solution for the question as it was asked, Next step if needed is to give more information as you have just added now, and we can adjust the solution for the new information if needed. This is not a "pissing contest" but a PURE RUDENESS to down-vote my answer like it was spam or even bad solution for the question as it is, in order to promote another answer. This act can only be a result of poor understanding or abusive other answers.

Comment: @user11047859, regarding the new information, I highly recommend you to read what say the person who actually wrote this solution which is **Jeff Moden** (by the way, I respect that Alan in this point that he remembered to mentioned it). As I remember Jeff explicitly mention that SQLCLR is twice to three times faster from his solution. I understand that people want fast solution and maybe learning something new (if this is new) is something that take time, but I HIGHLY recommend  You to check the option of using SQLCLRfor your case.

Comment: By the way,  you can guarantee order using STRING_SPLIT but this off-topic and probably does not fit your needs since when we have multiple duplicates in the result then the performance becomes VERY low. You can check the blog I upload yesterday,for full example (again, just for fun since it is probably NOT fit your needs).

Comment: Anyway, My answer, which is legit and fits the question, is still having minus points which is looking VERY bad and really annoying (the amount of points is not important but the fact that a good answer got "down-vote" by someone is ANNOYING!!!), but this is not relevant, and I am glad to see that you have a solution which you think that it fit you :-)