# TSQL: Grouping continuous timeslots together

Tags: t-sql

I have to group continuous timeslots together:

Example:

```
DECLARE @TEST as Table (ID int, tFrom datetime, tUntil dateTime)
insert into @TEST Values (1,'2019-1-1 12:00', '2019-1-1 13:00')
insert into @TEST Values (1,'2019-1-1 13:00', '2019-1-1 14:00')
insert into @TEST Values (1,'2019-1-1 14:00', '2019-1-1 16:00')
insert into @TEST Values (1,'2019-1-1 18:00', '2019-1-1 19:00')
insert into @TEST Values (1,'2019-1-1 19:00', '2019-1-1 20:00')
insert into @TEST Values (1,'2019-1-1 20:00', '2019-1-1 21:00')
insert into @TEST Values (1,'2019-1-1 22:00', '2019-1-1 23:00')
insert into @TEST Values (2,'2019-1-1 12:00', '2019-1-1 13:00')
insert into @TEST Values (2,'2019-1-1 13:00', '2019-1-1 14:00')
insert into @TEST Values (2,'2019-1-1 14:00', '2019-1-1 16:00')
insert into @TEST Values (2,'2019-1-1 18:00', '2019-1-1 19:00')
insert into @TEST Values (2,'2019-1-1 19:00', '2019-1-1 20:00')
insert into @TEST Values (2,'2019-1-1 20:00', '2019-1-1 21:00')
insert into @TEST Values (2,'2019-1-1 22:00', '2019-1-1 23:00')
```

Expected result:

```
1; 2019-1-1 12:00; 2019-1-1 16:00
1; 2019-1-1 18:00; 2019-1-1 21:00
1; 2019-1-1 22:00; 2019-1-1 23:00
2; 2019-1-1 12:00; 2019-1-1 16:00
2; 2019-1-1 18:00; 2019-1-1 21:00
2; 2019-1-1 22:00; 2019-1-1 23:00
```

Comment: Kudos for posting proper sample data and desired results. If you would have been a better question if you would also post your current attempts at solving this problem.

Comment: Is the difference between `tFrom` and `tUntil` always one hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classing gaps-and-islands problem.
The key here is how to identify the groups.

If the difference between `tFrom` and `tUntil` is always exactly one hour, you can ignore the tUntil and work only based on the differences between `tFrom` of different records.
Use a common table expression to identify the groups, and then select `min(tFrom)` and `max(tUntil)` from it, grouped by id and group.

What you do is calculate the hours difference between the `tFrom` and some fixed date, and you subtract that value from `row_number` ordered by `tFrom` (and partitioned by `id` in this case).

This means that consecutive values of `tFrom` will get the same group key (consecutive here means by the hour in this case):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  ID, 
            tFrom, 
            tUntil,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id  ORDER BY tFrom) - 
            DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2019-01-01', tFrom) As grp
    FROM @Test
)

SELECT  ID, 
        MIN(tFrom) As tFrom, 
        MAX(tUntil) As tUntil         
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID, grp
ORDER BY Id, tFrom
```

If the difference between `tFrom` and `tUntill` is not fixed, than it's going to be more cumbersome to identify the groups.
I came up with a solution involving three common table expressions - the first is to get the datediff between the current row's `tUntill` and the next row's `tFrom`, then calculate a group divider based on previous row's difference, and then calculate the group id based on sums of the dividers:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  ID, 
            tFrom, 
            tUntil,
            DATEDIFF(HOUR, tUntil, LEAD(tFrom) OVER(PARTITION BY id  ORDER BY tFrom)) As DiffNext
    FROM @Test
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  ID, 
            tFrom, 
            tUntil,
            ISNULL(SIGN(LAG(DiffNext) OVER(PARTITION BY id  ORDER BY tFrom)), 1) AS GroupDivider
    FROM CTE1
), CTE3 AS
(
    SELECT  ID, 
            tFrom, 
            tUntil,
            SUM(GroupDivider) OVER(PARTITION BY id  ORDER BY tFrom) As GroupId
    FROM CTE2
)

SELECT  ID, 
        MIN(tFrom) As tFrom, 
        MAX(tUntil) As tUntil
FROM CTE3
GROUP BY ID, GroupId
ORDER BY ID, tFrom
```

Comment: Dear Zohar, thanks a lot! This is working perfectly. As I am not so experienced with this stuff I will try to understand what you did here. Magic :-).

Comment: If you need a clarification simply ask... Glad to help :-)

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled, this solution will not work if you have overlap in the ranges of the time. For example try to add another row `insert into TEST Values (1,'2019-1-1 10:00', '2019-1-1 23:00')` ,and now you supposed to get only one row in the result set for ID = 1 but you still get three rows

Comment: @Ronen good point. Sample data did not contain overlapping rows. In case there are, it's possible to add another step to merge overlapping rows

Comment: Actually the solution is simple. All that need to be done is to split the ranges into points in time (using numbers/calendar table) -> use DISTINCT -> and combine the points in time to new ranges of time.

Comment: @ronen I had a feeling I'm over complicating things here. Care to add a simpler answer?

Comment: I am not sure that I want to spend my time in writing detailed answers at stackoverflow [after my last attempt to help someone here with detailed response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54640297/converting-a-table-with-a-key-and-comment-field-into-a-key-and-row-for-every-wor/54641792#54641792). @Alan Burstein can give more information on the issue... How come a perfect answer end up with minus points! Answer with several options, which fit the **original** question (before we got more information) and **the OP said explicitly that it answer his question**...

Comment: @ronen sometimes so feels like a popularity contest. It as annoying but in time, most good answers gets upvoted

Comment: @RonenAriely I've seen Alan around here. we've occasionally posted answers to same questions, but I don't remember getting downvotes on these question. My point is that the downvote could have been from anyone with high enough reputation (IIRC 125) - but I don't think it was from Alan. He does seem to have a tendency for self promoting, but not at the expense of other SO members. I used to get pissed anytime one of my answers was downvoted but I've realized that even when I know I'm correct, some people will still think I'm wrong, and there's nothing I can do about it [to be continued...]

Comment: @RonenAriely [continue]. Personally, I don't think downvoting is such a terrible idea, however I do think that any downvote should come with a comment from the downvoter explaining why they think a post deserves it. It's easy enough to implement while keeping the votes anonymous and would make downvotes a tool that can really help posts improve, not just piss off people.

Comment: Hey Zohar and Ronen: First of all thanks a lot for your help. During using the code you provided in the real world I found these overlapping situations. Thats weired :-(. Do you have an idea how I can handle this? Zohar you wrote something to add another step to merge overlapping rows. Do you have an example for that?

Here is an example:

Comment: I'm having a bit of a block attempting to get a good solution for overlapping rows. Perhaps @RonenAriely or another expert will be kind enough to offer a better solution than what I came up with.

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled, for you anything `:-)`. I will provide a full solution(s) - there are several options, the common option which is using the "Gaps and Islands" logic,which I mentioned before, and there is my secrete solution which was not yet publish in blog but I did mentioned it several times in lectures and in forums... It is 00:30 AM now and I go to sleep. `I hope to have time tomorrow evening` to post a blog with the solution(s).P.s @ZoharPeled you can always contact me in private on Facebook. No need to wait that I will come here why mistake :-)

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

In order to have a flexible solution which cover overlap in the ranges of the time, there are several solutions which we can use. "**Gaps & Islands**" approach is not the best (from the performance point of view), but it will work, and there are worse options as well (like using loop/cursor). Since "Gaps & Islands" was the phrase that mentioned in the comments and in the solution which was discuss in the comments, l will first show this solution in short.

The solution using the "Gaps & Islands" approach is based on two steps (one query which use CTE). First, you split the ranges into "points in time". Next using "numbers" table or better in this case a "Times" table, you can get the final result SET by finding the gaps between the points, which is classic "Gaps & Islands" problem.

I HIGHLY recommend to [follow the post, which I published](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/227/Grouping-continuous-Ranges-together-Part-1-Gaps-and-Islands-approach.aspx), and **follow it from start to end**! There are limitations and disadvantages for this approach, which you must understand. Moreover, the post present the "way of thinking" and how we solve problems like this one step-by-step.

In the post I start with the simplest case of **ranges of integers**, for example 2-4, 6-8, 8-10, 13-14 which should be grouped into 2-4, 6-10, 13-14.

Next I move to explain issue related to the resolution of space between the ranges, and I present a solution for Ranges of **Decimal numbers**, which cover the issue.

Finally, using the solution which I presented in detail for INTEGERS, I presented a solution for "Grouping continuous **time-slots** together", which was the original question in the forum.

**Note!** The solution which presented here is probably the one which I recommend to use in production. In my next post I published a totally different approach using my personal trick, which can improve performance dramatically.

In short, for the sake of the discussion I will create a Times table (you can use Numbers table directly if you really want). Notice that I create the Times table using a Numbers table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Times
GO
SELECT DT = DATEADD(MINUTE, N*10, '2010-01-01')
    INTO Times
FROM Numbers
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_DT ON Times(DT)
GO
SELECT TOP 1000 DT from Times
GO
```

and using this table we can solve the issue

```
;With MyCTE01 as (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, DT
    FROM TEST t
    INNER JOIN Times dt ON DT between tFrom and tUntil
)
,MyCTE02 as(
    SELECT ID, DT,
        MyGroup =
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                DATEADD(MINUTE, 10 * ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID,DT),0),
                DT
            )
    from MyCTE01
    --order by ID,DT
)
SELECT ID, MIN(DT) tFrom, MAX(DT) tUntil
FROM MyCTE02
GROUP BY ID, MyGroup
ORDER BY ID, tFrom
GO
```

**Note!** I highly [recommend to check the second post](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/228/Grouping-continuous-Ranges-together-Part-2-Using-geometry-Data-type.aspx) (Part 2) before choosing the solution that fit you in production.

**I hope that this cover the discussion and that it was helpful**

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled, you are welcome to check the solutions (i published here the "Gaps & Islands" approach as requested, and I published a post about another approach.

Comment: Hi @tommired, please inform me if something is not clear. I will be happy to elaborate more :-)